# Usage of Estrena

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

This evening, I stopped into a local magazine shop and picked up the most recent issue available of a magazine that appears to be targeting those concerned with the latest female fashion trends.

One of the taglines on the cover reads:

> Estrena
>
> Lo que triunfará esta primavera

My questions involves the use of *estrena*. Of course, it is a tense of the verb *estrenar*, but it seems that the editors are using it as a way of saying something like *Preview - What will triumph this Spring*.

Is this correct?  It just seems like it is the wrong person.  To me, if they use *estrenar* in this context, why don't they use something like *estrenamos*?

Comment: *Estrenar* doesn't mean *to preview*, it means *to show off (for the first time) ~ to premiere*.

Answer (score 3):

The tagline means

> Wear something new

because, as @guifa said in a comment, *estrenar* means *to premiere*.  In the context of clothes, it means to wear something for the first time.  Men can do it too.  Suppose my son has been given a tie for his birthday, and is playing a concert the next day.  I might ask him, as he's preparing his concert clothes,

> ¿Quieres estrenar la nueva corbata?

Also, if person A, wearing a new outfit, runs into a close friend, person B, who knows A well enough to notice that the outfit is new, then B might say, in an admiring voice,

> ¿Estás estrenando?  ¡Guapo/a!

Are you wearing something new?  Lovely!

In short, the magazine is encouraging its readers to go out and buy new clothes.  The two taglines together are then, loosely:

> Wear something new
>
> What's hot for spring

They are two totally separate sentences (taglines).

(I like that word, *tagline*.)

---

**Update**:

Here is what the relevant part of the cover looked like:

[image: Vanidades cover image]

Comment: Fair enough.  So the editors are using the imperative of estrenar to say, "Hey, reader!  Show off the clothes that will triumph this Spring!"?

Comment: @Blamettu - Yes.  I'm sorry, I forgot to talk about the triumph part.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @blamettu maybe, or if there's a person on the cover, it may be third person singular, saying that they are showing off a collection

Comment: @guifa - Good point.  I forgot about that option.  But I think if it's about Dior unveiling a collection, then the tagline would be "Dior estrena".  Don't you think?

Comment: @aparente001 depends but probably.  I think we'd need time see the cover to know for sure.

Comment: @guifa - The magazine I am referring to is the April 2017 issue of Vanidades magazine.

Comment: @guifa - Was able to find the cover in question thanks to the date provided by OP.

Comment: @aparente001 nice find. Basically it's saying "show off what's gonna [ be popular | work ] this summer"

Comment: "Primavera" doesn't refer to spring in this context?  Or should/could one assume that what works in spring will work in the summer and therefore "primavera" should be interpreted loosely?

Comment: @Blamettu - I'm not sure whether we will be reliable fashion advisors here -- but I would take "primavera" here to mean "spring."

Comment: @guifa - Oh dear, now we have to figure out how much separation they intended with that funny black cross.

Comment: It is. I just remembered it wrong as I was typing. On mobile so I couldn't see comments and the image at the same time